# Read ffmpeg segment on stdout

Tags: ffmpeg, pipe

I'm trying to segment a video file to play it in the browser. Ideally, I would like to read the stdout and pipe it to the browser, but if I enable segmentation it doesn't work:

`$ ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -f segment -segment_format mp4 -segment_format_options movflags=+faststart+frag_keyframe+empty_moov+default_base_moof pipe:1
...
Output #0, segment, to 'pipe:1':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream`

1) Can segmented files be written to stdout? Is there a special character for file separation?

2) Otherwise, how can I detect a new keyframe just by reading the byte stream?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I ended up writing file chunks to ramdisk, read them and then stream over http. Pretty similar, even if more wasteful.

Comment: I found out that segmented outputs don't get sent to stdout. The stdout receives a constant stream of data sadly.